# Rewriting lines from the ending

Tags: vim

I want to read a file and write its lines from the ending (which means that I want to replace the first line with the last line, the second line with the penultimate line and so on) just by using VIM features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g/^/m0` will reverse the entirety of the current buffer (it continually matches lines and moves them to the first line in the buffer).